Conexion a base de datos sybase y php version 8
Estoy trabajando en un sitio que trabaja en la version 5.4 de php, lo estoy actualizando a php version 8, en la version del sitio 5.4 se utiliza la libreria adodb para la conexion a la base de datos, ahora que quiero hacer la conexion en el sitio actualizado no puedo utilizar adodb siendo que actualice lalibreia para la version de php 8, intente por medio de ODBC y FreeTDS, PDO y dblib, pero aun asi no logro tener la conexion. (ojo haciendo las configuraciones correspondientes en los archivos de configuracion)
Codigo para la conexion:

    <?
    $dsn = "dblib:host=nombre_o_IP_del_servidor:5000;dbname=nombre_de_la_base_de_datos";
    $username = "usuario";
    $password = "contraseña";
    
    try {
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        echo "Conexión exitosa a Sybase";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error de conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>


resultado con ODBC:
Error de conexión: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
y me arroja el siguiente resultado con dblib:
Error de conexión: could not find driver

Por favor, mira las verificaciones / configuraciones sugeridas en las respuestas a esta pregunta.
